# Upgraded to 12.04, still displays the old login screen

Tags: login-screen, partial-upgrade

The login screen still says Ubuntu 11.10. Needless to say, the upgrade was interrupted. I was able to continue the interrupted upgrade and get a stable machine.

`lsb_release -a` tells me its 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try, in a terminal:`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
Which may help, or at least give some clues.

Comment: Oh, I did not know of the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` command. All I was doing was `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: sudo apt-get update (not upgrade) updates the data on which updates are available.  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade gets and applies all the updates.  does that mean it is all ok now?

Comment: Yes, its resolved now. Although what was worrying is that the screen blanked out a few times and I had to log into a tty to kill gnome-session and wait until the CPU processing stopped, restart, then continue again. I hope others aren't having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```